# Django cache different content for same page

Tags: django, caching

I have a page that shows a list of products. I was showing all products in the list at every request, so I was using the standard cache middlewares provided by django.

Now I'm going to limit the number of products shown and would like to cache every intermediary result in the cache as well, so I don't need to generate all the pages all the time. Example: Suppose I have 9 products in the list and will show 3 products at a time.

I'll have one page with products from 0 to 2, from 3 to 5, from 6 to 8. The URL to access all of them will be the same. Is it possible use the standard cache middlewares adding something to the "Vary" header for example? Can I add the initial index (0, 3 or 6) somewhere, so I can use one of the standard decorators?

Comment: There exists [django-pagination](http://code.google.com/p/django-pagination/) - It could be handy in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I'm caching the response returned by render_to_response inside the view, based on a suggestion in the #django irc channel

Answer (score 0):

You should add some more description to your question like, the middleware that you are using and/or the view decorators involved.

What I can say is that Django will care about GET parameters by itself, so if you have a url like

/list/?page=1

the page cache for that will have a different cache key than

/list/?page=2